# Show specific value in each row of an Excel range depending on time

Tags: excel, vba

I want to enter a specific value (A, B or C) based on time.

- A when time is between 14 - 22
- B when time is between 5 am - 14
- C when time is between 22 - 5 am.

I have data this way: 18-08-2022 10:28:29

I'm stuck with the following:

```vb
If Time => TimeValue("22:00:01") And Time <= TimeValue("05:00:00 AM") Then
    wksCurSheet.Range("G", Target.Row).Value = "C"
    If Time => TimeValue("05:00:01 AM") And Time <= TimeValue("14:00:00") Then
        wksCurSheet.Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = "B"
        If Time => TimeValue("14:00:01") And Time <= TimeValue("22:00:00") Then
            wksCurSheet.Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = "A"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: finally tested...

You would use `ElseIf` here:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 7 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Time > TimeValue("05:00:00 AM") And Time <= TimeValue("14:00:00") Then
        Me.Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = "B"
    ElseIf Time > TimeValue("14:00:00") And Time <= TimeValue("22:00:00") Then
        Me.Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = "A"
    Else
        Me.Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = "C" 'any other time
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i continue getting error while running the macro

Comment: "getting error" is not a very useful description of exactly what happens when you run your code.  What error are you getting, and where?  It would help a lot if you edit your question to add the rest of the code.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73422848/edit